# Completeness of $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: real-analysis

In the proof below I don't understand how did Terence Tao construct $L$ integer $\frac{L}{n} < x_0$? [image]

Comment: That is nit rigorous though. The Archimedean property that I am familiar with is the following given $\epsilon > 0$ and $x$ real number. There exists M such that $M \epsilon > x$.

Comment: Are you allowed to choose $L$ negative? Then making $L/n<x_0$ is just making $(-L)/n>-x_0$ which is OK by Archimedian.

Comment: No I am not allowed making L negative. The precise statement of The Archimedean property is as follows:

Let x and $\epsilon$ be any positive real numbers. Then there exists a positive integer M such that $M \epsilon > x.$

Comment: But, Learner, $x_0$ might be negative. In that case, there is no positive integer $L$ such that $L/n<x_0$, since $L/n>0>x_0$.

Comment: Any thoughts above my comment, Learner?

Comment: Are you still here, Learner?

Comment: @GerryMyerson sorry I got busy. Yeah thank you so much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given a nonempty set $E$ of reals, an element $x_0$ of $E$, and a positive integer $n$, OP wants to know how to construct an integer $L$ such that $L/n<x_0$. In the comments, OP insists on $L$ being nonnegative.

But this is clearly impossible, if $x_0\le0$ (and there is nothing in the problem statement forbidding such an $x_0$). For if $x_0\le0$, then, since $n\ge1$, we have $nx_0\le0$, so if $L/n<x_0$ then $L<nx_0\le0$, contradicting the condition that $L$ be nonnegative.